# time stamp and mysql

Tags: mysql, json, sql-delete

I am making a simple angular + nodeJS + MySQL application, for learning purposes.

I am trying to understand how to use this table in MySQL Exchange before implementing the deletion in my app.

This is my table -

```
create table taskstable
(
instanceTime timestamp not null,
item varchar(45) not null,
email varchar(255) not null,
ischeck boolean not null,
foreign key (email) references usertable(email),
primary key (instanceTime, email)
);
```

And I insert these values (one at a time so they have different timestamps)

```
insert into taskstable
values (current_timestamp,"to call mom","admin@gmail.com",false);

insert into taskstable
values (current_timestamp,"write papter","admin@gmail.com",false);

insert into taskstable
values (current_timestamp,"paint chair","admin@gmail.com",false);
```

Now, these are the values in my table:

```
# instanceTime, item, email, ischeck
2018-02-10 16:19:12, to call mom, admin@gmail.com, 0
2018-02-10 16:19:29, write papter, admin@gmail.com, 0
2018-02-10 16:19:33, paint chair, admin@gmail.com, 0
```

And when I try to delete using this:

```
DELETE FROM taskstable
WHERE (current_timestamp like "2018-02-10 16:19:12" AND  email like "admin@gmail.com");
```

And the result is this: 
16:24:22    DELETE FROM taskstable WHERE (current_timestamp like "2018-02-10 16:19:12" AND  email like "admin@gmail.com")   0 row(s) affected   0.000 sec

Which means I don't use the timestamp object well. I am new in MySQL and not sure how to approach this.
How should I delete?

---

Edit, this was a mistake, I should of asked "instanceTime LIKE blabla"

But now, when I try to delete with my app, the Json receive the time info this way:
"instanceTime":"2018-02-10T14:19:29.000Z"
But SQL should be: "2018-02-10 14:19:29"

What is this formatting shown in the JSON? How to show the right formatting?!

Comment: Do you have the delete privilege for the table? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_delete

Comment: `WHERE (current_timestamp like "2018-02-10 16:19:12"`... does this make sense? Maybe you mean `WHERE (instanceTime  like '...`, otherwise the query only deletes everything when executed exactly at the given time. You compare the execution time with a fix value, you do not, however, compare the data stored in the field `instanceTime`

Comment: Lol. That was a stupid mistake.

Comment: thanks @Psi, that was obviously the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM 
    taskstable
WHERE 
    instanceTime = "2018-02-10 16:19:12" AND
    email = "admin@gmail.com"
```

You can delete like this.